# The result is different between node crypto module and javascript crypto.js for aes-256-cbc encrypting

Tags: javascript, cryptography

node result :

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

const cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes-256-cbc", '4016c630787211e9af11ad2b4e874da9');
let result = cipher.update('hello world', "utf8", "hex");
result += cipher.final("hex");
```

---

The result is c5c0a3f1923203ae52a6e2b207cf958f.

To compare with javascript,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<script>
var result = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("hello world", '4016c630787211e9af11ad2b4e874da9');
console.log(result.toString());
</script>
```

The result is U2FsdGVkX1+pi4FPkd9TW03MYZfOpsvcewQAT4oz5+o=

Why these results is different?

I don't know how to work node crypto module.

Answer (score 0):

The first is `hex` encoded, the second `base64`.

Also your `IV` may differ.